# how can I inherit of inherited model and view in odoo/openerp

Tags: odoo, openerp-7

I need help to set default value of `purchase_ok` field at `product_template` class in purchase module

thanks

Comment: You want to set the default value with a function?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply set the default attribute like this:

```python
class ProductTemplate(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'product.template'

    purchase_ok = fields.Boolean(
        string='Selectable on purchase operations',
        default=True,
    )
```

Or you can use a lambda function like this:

```python
class ProductTemplate(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'product.template'

    purchase_ok = fields.Boolean(
        string='Selectable on purchase operations',
        default=lambda self: self._get_default_purchase_ok(),
    )

@api.model
def _get_default_purchase_ok(self):

    value = True
    # some operations       

    return value
```

Comment: thank you very much for the quick response, but I have tried to implement both solutions and purchase_ok field value does not change, any idea what may be happening?

Comment: I tried the code and it works fine. Where are you trying to create the product? Are you importing well the class in your module? Make sure you are importing this as well: `from openerp import models, fields, api`